# Creating HTML form with Bootstrap togglable tabs, content not showing

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a form that has different fields when different tabs are opened up. I'm trying to use Bootstrap's togglable tabs, and it looks like it's working, but when you click on another tab, it doesn't show the other html that is supposed to show up in that particular div.

Here's my HTML:

```
<form name="quote" id="price-quote">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="service-tabs" class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active"><a href="#carpet-cleaning" data-toggle="tab">Carpet Cleaning</a></li>
            <li><a href="#upholstery-cleaning" data-toggle="tab">Upholstery Cleaning</a></li>
                </ul>

          <div class="tab-content clearfix">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">
                <h3>Carpet Cleaning Options</h3>
                    <!--how many bedrooms-->
                    <label class="control-label" for="carpet_cleaning">Bedrooms</label><br>
                        <select class="form-control-1" id="carpet_cleaning">
                            <option value="0">0</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                        </select>
             </div>

           <div class="tab-pane" id="2">
                <h3>Upholstery Cleaning Options</h3>
                    <!--how many dining room chairs-->
                    <label class="control-label" for="dining_chairs_cleaning">Dining Room Chairs (each)</label><br>
                        <select class="form-control-1" id="dining_chairs_cleaning">
                            <option value="0">0</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                        </select>
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

And here's a JS fiddle for a simpler view: https://jsfiddle.net/z2kt4hv0/

I've tried this using jQuery as well, but I thought it would be better with Bootstrap since I was already using it for other parts of the page. Everything seems like it should work, but the other tab won't show the right content. Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `href` attribute of the tab links needs to match the `id` of the section to display. And btw, `id`'s can't start with (or just be) a number.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form name="quote" id="price-quote">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="service-tabs" class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="#carpet-cleaning" data-toggle="tab">Carpet Cleaning</a></li>
        <li><a href="#upholstery-cleaning" data-toggle="tab">Upholstery Cleaning</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content clearfix">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="carpet-cleaning">
          <h3>Carpet Cleaning Options</h3>
          <!--how many bedrooms-->
          <label class="control-label" for="carpet_cleaning">Bedrooms</label>
          <br>
          <select class="form-control-1" id="carpet_cleaning">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="upholstery-cleaning">
          <h3>Upholstery Cleaning Options</h3>
          <!--how many dining room chairs-->
          <label class="control-label" for="dining_chairs_cleaning">Dining Room Chairs (each)</label>
          <br>
          <select class="form-control-1" id="dining_chairs_cleaning">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm realizing I overlooked quite a bit here. Thanks for the simple answer, I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` must be on the appropriate `tab-pane`. Update the tab-pane names..

`<div class="tab-pane active" id="carpet-cleaning">`

and

`<div class="tab-pane" id="upholstery-cleaning">`

http://www.bootply.com/8fPWTNGceE

Answer (score 1):

So, you shouldn't wrap the entire container in a form element. Instead only wrap it around actual form elements (i.e. your select and label tags). Here's a working example of what you're trying to do:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="pill">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Messages</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Note:** You need Bootrap.css, Bootstrap.js, and jQuery.js for this to work.

Just replace the content in the `.tab-pane` divs with whatever you want. You can see a full guide to using tabs on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp).

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question because it doesn't have the html `form` element present in the answer. You also talk about wrapping specific elements with form but don't do that in your example